# How to use GetPivotdata to extract data from a pivot table built from an Olap Cube?

Tags: excel, pivot, olap

With a normal excel Pivot tables you can easily run a get pivot data to link to a static table to reference, for instance a product not in the same order as the pivot table. in essence it then becomes dynamic so that when the pivot table is updated the cells then update with the right information.

When using an OLAP cube driven pivot table the formula becomes very difficult to understand. how can i unpick it to do exactly the same thing?

What more information do i need to supply for this to make more sense??

Ive tried taking out the `""[Product].[PM Value Product].&[Tetley 1cup Decaf Black Tea Bags 40s Box]"` from the formula and replacing it with a cell reference. however it then comes back the #REF error

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("[Measures].[Weight Dist]",'Summary Data'!$G$7,"[Date - SalesOut].[Rolling 13]",
       "[Date - SalesOut].[Rolling 13].[MAT Year].&[Year Ago]",
       "[Product].[PM Value Product]",
       PM Value Product].&[Tetley 1cup Decaf Black Tea Bags 40s Box]",
       "[Customer].[Customer Types]",
       "[Customer].[Customer Types].[Symbol Store].&[Xtra Local]")
```